# How to reset/restore preferences in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I was trying to see the compared documents side by side (using `review, compare, compare`). I accidentarly close one windows and I don't know how to restore that.

I close Word and reopen it but stills not showing than window.

How can I restore or reset all the Word options and preferences?

Comment: Try the fit it here or else look it over for a starting point potentially at least.... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/822005/how-to-reset-user-options-and-registry-settings-in-word

Answer (score 0):

If you closed one document when comparing two documents side by side, we can use the following setting to restore the closed one:

Review tab, click **Compare** > **Show Source Documents** > **Show Both**.

[image]